# DirectAdmin create subdomain programmatically using PHP

Tags: php, debian, subdomain, directadmin

I created subdomain in DirectAdmin using his admin panel. But I want to do the same from PHP.
I have to add section to the `httpd.conf` and create folder in `public_html` folder. And then add to DNS. But I have to do using PHP or using DirectAdmin API? Because I don't know if there are any other places where I have to add information about my new subdomain.
For example in this folder:

```
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/mydomain.subdomains
```

Comment: You don't have to touch that folder. That folder is autogenerated by the DA system.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whatyou want to add to the DNS but da will create your a record. If you want to add more DNS records you can use the API.

> CMD_API_DNS_ADMIN?action=edit&domain=domain.com&type=A&arecs0=name%3Dmail%26value%3D1.2.3.4&name=mail&value=1.2.3.5

To create files or directorys you can use the hools system. All hooks, i.e. custom scripts should be placed under /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom/.

you will need to create desired scripts first, then set correct permissions, and populate them with a needed content.
Directory: /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom/
Permissions: 700
Ownership: diradmin:diradmin

I geuss you can use subdomain_create_pre.sh